# Yammer, create custom Open Graph Objects

Tags: yammer

I have seen that the Yammer Social Platform allows for creation of custom actions and object types, but I've found very poor [documentation](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/custom-types) on this so far.

I'd like to create custom Open Graph Objects with an arbitrary JSON structure. Is it possible? Does Yammer provide 100% flexibility creating such Objects?

Thank you very much,

--Andrea